# System.Printing.PrintQueueException: PrintTicket provider failed to bind to printer. Win32 error: Access is denied

Tags: c#, gembox-document

I have an application where I want to print a Word document.
I am using third party GemBox software, and in my development environment this code works;

```
public void OutputLetter(string outputFile, string placeholder, string newText)
{
    using (var document = DocX.Load(this.InputFile))
    {
        document.ReplaceText(placeholder, newText);
        document.SaveAs(outputFile);
    }

    this.PrintDocument(outputFile);
}

private void PrintDocument(string outputFile)
{
    var document = DocumentModel.Load(outputFile, LoadOptions.DocxDefault);
    document.Print(AppSettings.PrinterName);
}
```

AppSettings.PrinterName is the name of the printer stored in web.config.
Once I deploy it, I get this error on the line; "document.Print(AppSettings.PrinterName);"

```
System.Printing.PrintQueueException: PrintTicket provider failed to bind to printer. Win32 error: Access is denied.
```

On the event viewer I get;

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{BA7C0D29-81CA-4901-B450-634E20BB8C34}
 and APPID 
{AA0B85DA-FDDF-4272-8D1D-FF9B966D75B0}
 to the user IIS APPPOOL\Mulalley SID (S-1-5-82-1744840036-3971326342-2272496405-1389653927-2904033151) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it could be this issue [Microsoft bk2872151](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872151)

They provide a fix-it for users, the suggested solution for developers is to make sure you are not running in 32bit mode on a 64bit server (i.e. switch to AnyCPU).

Note that in VS2013 there is also an extra check box for prefer 32Bit even if you pick AnyCPU