# Windows service: PrintTicket provider failed to bind to printer. Win32 error: -2147467231

Tags: c#, winapi, printing

Printing from a service hosted as a windows service(32-bit)is throwing an exception.

**Exception:**
PrintTicket provider failed to bind to printer. Win32 error: -2147467231

The method works fine when hosted as a console app(32-bit) however when hosted as a windows service it throws the exception.

```
private void Print(PrintJob printJob, string templateXaml)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                dynamic labelDataObject = CreateDynamicObject(printJob.LabelData);
                PrintQueue queue = GetPrintQueue(printJob.PrintQueue);
                PrintTicket ticket = queue.DefaultPrintTicket;
                ticket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
                FixedPage page = RenderPage(new Size(ticket.PageMediaSize.Width.Value, ticket.PageMediaSize.Height.Value), labelDataObject, templateXaml);

                XpsDocumentWriter xpsWriter = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(queue);
                xpsWriter.Write(page, ticket);
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
                //TODO: Logging and notification
            }
        });
        t.IsBackground = false;
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
    }
```

I have tried running the service under adminstrator, the current logged in user, and local system account. Nothing works so far. Please help:/

Comment: Did you try searching? [Is it a 64-bit machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566594/system-printing-printqueueexception-printticket-provider-failed-to-bind-to-prin)?

Comment: Error code 0x800004021 (-2147467231) translates to "The operation attempted is not supported.".

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem: Sending XPS files to a printer from a 32bit windows service using .net framework failed with an error message.

According to MS support, there are 2 solutions:

1. use a 64bit windows service
2. apply the registry modification described in Knowledge Base Article 2954953

Hope this solves your problem!